# Actual used memory for mqueue

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to find a command to get the actual reserved memory for `mqueue`.

In `/proc/self/limits` is stored limit of total size for `mqueue` (in my case 819200).

It means that if I have 10 `mqueues` with a limit of 10 msg and size 8192, then total size is `10*10*8192=819200` which is number in system limit.

I know how to increase this limit but I don't know how to get the actual used memory for `mqueue` (for example if I'm currently using 6 `mqueues`).

- if I cretate 6 mqueues with settings 10 msg and size 8192,
- then alocated memory will be 6*10*8192 = 491520
- and my question is where I can found this size 491520

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <cerrno>
  #include <cstring>
  #include <stdexcept>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string>
  #include "mqueue.h"

  std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
      char buffer[128];
      std::string result = "";
      FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
      if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
      try {
          while (!feof(pipe)) {
              if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
                  result += buffer;
          }
      } catch (...) {
          pclose(pipe);
          throw;
      }
      pclose(pipe);
      return result;
  }

  class mqueue {
  public:
      mqueue(std::string n = "/dummy", int maxMsg = 10) : queue(), attr(), name(n) {
      /* Set attributes */
      this->attr.mq_flags = 0;
      this->attr.mq_maxmsg =  maxMsg; /* war: MAX_MSG_QUEUE */
      this->attr.mq_msgsize = 8192; /* war: MAX_MSG_SIZE */

      /* Destroy old message queue */
      mq_unlink(this->name.c_str());

      /* Open message queue */
      queue = mq_open(this->name.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG, &this->attr);
      std::cout << "\n[info] in constructor class mqueue name: " << this->name << " | errno: " << std::strerror(errno);
     }
      ~ mqueue() {
          //std::cout << "\n[info] in destructor class mqueue name: " << this->name << " | close = " << mq_close(this->queue) << " | unlink = " << mq_unlink(this->name.c_str());
      }
      void getInfo() const {
          std::cout << "\nname: " << this->name << " | mqueue: " << this->queue << "\n" ;
      }
  private:
      std::string name;
      mqd_t queue;
      mq_attr attr;
  };

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      int i;
      mqueue testMqueue("/dummy");
      testMqueue.getInfo();

      mqueue testMqueue1("/dummy1", 1);
      mqueue testMqueue2("/dummy2", 6);
      mqueue testMqueue3("/dummy3", 7);
      mqueue testMqueue4("/dummy4", 10);
      mqueue testMqueue5("/dummy5", 2);
      mqueue testMqueue6("/dummy6", 3);

      mqd_t mqdes;
      mq_attr mqstat;
      for (i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
          mqdes = i;
          mq_getattr(mqdes, &mqstat);
          std::cout << "\n" << i << "\tmaxmsg: " << mqstat.mq_maxmsg << "\tmsgsize: " << mqstat.mq_msgsize << "\tsize: " << mqstat.mq_maxmsg * mqstat.mq_msgsize;
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Thanks for answers.
Adrian

Example:

Compile and execute:

```
std::vector<mqueue> testMqueue;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    testMqueue.push_back(mqueue("/dummy" + std::to_string(i)));
    testMqueue.at(i).getInfo(); 
}
std::cout << exec("ipcs -q") ;
```

and as you can see:

```
[info] in constructor class mqueue name: /dummy19 | errno: Too many open files
 name: /dummy19 | mqueue: -1

 ------ Message Queues --------
 key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages
```

**list is empty also when I executing ipcs -q in terminal**

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview - follow this to the section about mounting mqueues as virtual file system